# Unable to scrape a website which requires login using Python, beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation

I am using beautifulsoup4 and mechanize library with python to automate a few scenarios in my web application. Basically, I want to perform below step:
1) open website URL
2) Enter user name and password and click on the login button
3) Verify if logged-in successfully
4) Logout.

Below is my code to do the above steps:

```
import mechanize
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

LOGIN_URL = 'www.xyz.com/login.aspx'
UserName = 'Username'
Password = 'Password'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open(LOGIN_URL)


# Select the second (index one) form (the first form is a search query box)
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['txtUserId'] = UserName
br.form['txtPassword'] = Password

# Login
br.submit()
mainpage = br.response().read()
```

every time, I am getting the same response i.e. status code 200 even though the password is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Use CasperJS based on PhantomJS to achieve this.

Comment: so what do you expect the response to be?

Comment: Using `python Selenium` is more effective for creating bot